Failed to connect Firebase services after exiting Firebase Emulators
I've follow the instructions on Firebase Emulators Suite's doc from https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure. The Firebase Emulators works, e.g. Auth and Firestore. But when I exit emulators using Ctrl + C, and then try to add new data to Firestore. It doesn't work. Hope someone can help!
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import {connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider()

connectAuthEmulator(auth,'http://localhost:9099');
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);

The error message in the console:
firebase_firestore.js?v=b5d4dfea:1775 
POST http://localhost:8080/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fsalon-project-43926%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=85555&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&zx=rqw6jovafaan&t=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED


Have tried reopen the terminal

I don't understand what the problem is.  If you exit the emulators, of course the code that depends on connecting to the emulator will no longer be able to add data.  Are you expecting something different to happen?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@DougStevenson thanks for the reply. Sorry this was a stupid question and I wasn't being clear. The mistake was I forgot to remove connectAuthEmulator and connectFirestoreEmulator when I tried to disconnect from the emulators.
